# How to ask complex questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, reopen-closed

A few months ago, I used DataGrid in WPF to basically enable user to edit and add new record with validations. I have met and solved difficulties/bugs in using the DataGrid, and with more troubles I get, the more I feel I could write them down so that it can benefit others, as I feel my task is very typical, so my problems will be repeated by others.

As a result I have posted this question on SO: [DataGrid so hard to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814501/datagrid-so-hard-to-use) (I must admit the title is not great).
In the question, I have listed step by step (as they are happened somewhat in sequence, as when dealing with error1, the side effect is error2.. etc.) which difficulties/bugs/errors I have met and how I have solved them.  And in the end, I have raised my question: *Am I using the DataGrid wrong?*

I feel this is in line with *a specific programming problem* as I could just list the last step/bugs and ask how to avoid it. But as all the other steps are relevant to reproduce that (and contains useful information of common bugs&solutions), I choose to listed them all.

I realised that there may be no easy answers to my question, and personally, I feel the question itself will be good knowledge for others who will use DataGrid trying to achieve the same thing, but it finally get closed by the community as too broad:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.

I respect their decisions but how could I revise it better to cover what I want (and should) to cover? Is more information equal to too broad? Maybe it's better to be a community wiki as it covers more than one question?

I've voted to reopen it, and received another support vote (I think), but again, I found it still in close stage after review (so reopen rejected).

I think complicated questions (which involved a lot research works in my opinion) is good for SO, but how can I ask it in a better way, so that it can get better response? Or am I posting in the wrong site?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a code review.  There is a site specifically for code reviews.

That question is not appropriate on SO because SO's scope states that it is for *specific* programming problems, which is not what you have here.

Comment: Note that "a code review" is NOT the same as posting a question on [codereview.se]. You need someone to sit down beside you and go through the code with you.

Comment: @ChrisF, so I guess this is not suitable on SE net and get closed?

Comment: @Bolu - it might be OK for [codereview.se] - especially if you can split the code up - but you'll have see how to ask a good question there. I'm not active on the site so I can't say.

Comment: @Bolu first thing to get there is to make sure your answer is yes to [all six questions in their help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) "Does my question contain... etc". If any of the answers is _no_, I'd bet 10:1 that your question will be closed (the questions are simple and quite easy to verify)

Comment: @gnat, many thank. By looking at that, I feel that my problem may not fit Code Review. As I have to just give example code (in xaml) as the code from the real project will be too long and contain too much noises.

Comment: I feel this is in line with *a specific programming problem* as I could just list the last step/bug and ask how to avoid it. But all the other steps are relevant to reproduce that shouldn't I listed them all?

Comment: @Bolu "What are all of the things that I've done wrong" or "how do I make this code better" is not a *specific* problem.  It is a very broad problem with tons of radically different types of answers, none of which can ever be asserted as *the* correct answer.